# Spring Web MVC with Java Configuration Error

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using Java Configuration for my Spring Web Application but it continues to look for a dispatcher xml file in Spring STS. How do I make this change? I have change the context in the properties of my project to my `WebConfig class`. Attached is the log file:

```
       12:02:08.157 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Initializing servlet 'dispatcher'
Nov 19, 2014 12:02:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
12:02:08.157 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet     'dispatcher': initialization started
12:02:08.157 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Servlet with name   'dispatcher' will try to create custom WebApplicationContext context of class    'org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext',      
 using parent context [Root     WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Nov 19 11:58:48 EST     2014]; root of context hierarchy]
12:02:08.158 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for  key 'spring.profiles.active' in [servletConfigInitParams]
12:02:08.158 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.profiles.active' in [servletContextInitParams]
  12:02:08.158 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.profiles.active' in [jndiProperties]
12:02:08.158 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/spring.profiles.active]
12:02:08.159 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name   [java:comp/env/spring.profiles.active] not found - trying original name [spring.profiles.active].   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [spring.profiles.active] is not bound in this Context.   Unable to find [spring.profiles.active].
12:02:08.159 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI  object with name [spring.profiles.active]
12:02:08.159 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name     [spring.profiles.active] threw NamingException with message: Name [spring.profiles.active] is not  bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.profiles.active].. Returning null.
12:02:08.159 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.profiles.active' in [systemProperties]
12:02:08.159 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.profiles.active' in [systemEnvironment]
12:02:08.159 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'spring.profiles.active' in any property source. Returning [null]
12:02:08.159 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.profiles.default' in [servletConfigInitParams]
12:02:08.159 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.profiles.default' in [servletContextInitParams]
12:02:08.159 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.profiles.default' in [jndiProperties]
12:02:08.159 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/spring.profiles.default]
12:02:08.160 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/spring.profiles.default] not found - trying original name [spring.profiles.default]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [spring.profiles.default] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.profiles.default].
 12:02:08.160 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [spring.profiles.default]
12:02:08.160 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [spring.profiles.default] threw NamingException with message: Name [spring.profiles.default] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.profiles.default].. Returning null.
 12:02:08.160 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.profiles.default' in [systemProperties]
12:02:08.160 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.profiles.default' in [systemEnvironment]
12:02:08.160 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'spring.profiles.default' in any property source. Returning [null]
 12:02:08.160 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.profiles.default' in [servletConfigInitParams]
 12:02:08.160 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.profiles.default' in [servletContextInitParams]
12:02:08.160 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.profiles.default' in [jndiProperties]
12:02:08.160 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/spring.profiles.default]
 12:02:08.161 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/spring.profiles.default] not found - trying original name [spring.profiles.default].  javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [spring.profiles.default] is not bound in this Context.  Unable to find [spring.profiles.default].
12:02:08.161 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [spring.profiles.default]
  12:02:08.161 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [spring.profiles.default] threw NamingException with message: Name [spring.profiles.default] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.profiles.default].. Returning null.
   12:02:08.161 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.profiles.default' in [systemProperties]
  12:02:08.161 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.profiles.default' in [systemEnvironment]
  12:02:08.161 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'spring.profiles.default' in any property source. Returning [null]
12:02:08.161 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Wed Nov 19 12:02:08 EST 2014]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
 12:02:08.162 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
  12:02:08.162 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
  12:02:08.162 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
  12:02:08.162 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
  12:02:08.163 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] ERROR o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML  document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is  java.io.FileNotFoundException:  
 Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring STS did not include my classes folder in the target folder for Deployment Properties. Once I added this, everything worked.